# UIAlertController as ActionSheet not correctly sized in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Currently the issue I am facing is while showing a `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` as it's preferred style, and adding a button with `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` results in display problems. *The presented _UIPopoverView's frame isn't large enough to display the whole action sheet.*

**Here is the code:-**

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self presentActionSheetFromSender:sender withCancelButtonStyel:UIAlertActionStyleCancel];
}



- (void)presentActionSheetFromSender:(UIButton *)sender withCancelButtonStyel:(UIAlertActionStyle)cancelButtonStyle {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TestController" message:@"TestMessage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds;
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender;

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:cancelButtonStyle handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**So the current issue is that the  ActionSheet only shows the title and message, cutting off the Cancel button.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it helps this..

```
- (IBAction)btnshare:(id)sender
{

    NSString *cancelTitle = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?@"Cancel" : nil;
    popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Sharing    option:   " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
             @"Twitter",
             @"Facebook",
             @"Mail",
             @"TextMessage",
             nil];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        // In this case the device is an iPad..
        [popup showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        // In this case the device is an iPhone/iPod Touch.
        [popup showInView:self.view];

    }

    popup.tag = 1;
    [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help. My objective is not to show in keyWindow.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TestController" message:@"TestMessage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
```

Bcs you set `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`, so `UIAlertAction` style `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` is not working.

You can change one of them to fixed it.